# Formatting objects in array from Firebase Database in React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, lodash

I am testing pulling some data form Firebase Database, not sure if I am doing it correctly.

The data is stored like this in a Firebase Database db named "users"

```
[{
    "2022-01-30": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "22"
      },
      {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "21"
      }
   ],
   "2022-02-12": [
      {
        "name": "Greg",
        "age": "23"
      },
   ],
   "2022-03-16": [
      {
        "name": "Anne",
        "age": "24"
      },
   ]
}]
```

Which I am using a simple react native app.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    loadItems()
  }, []);

  const loadItems = async () => {
    await firebase.database().ref("users").get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let val = doc.val();
        val.forEach((element) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(element));
        });
      })
    })
  }
```

which returns

```
{ name: John, age: 22 }
{ name: Mary, age: 21 }
{ name: Greg, age: 23 }
{ name: Anne, age: 24 }
```

You'll notice it's missing the *commas* separating the objects.

I would like to format it like this:

```
[{ name: John, age: 22 },
{ name: Mary, age: 21 },
{ name: Greg, age: 23 },
{ name: Anne, age: 24 }]
```

so I can display in a searchable flatlist and other places etc.

Any help appreciated

Comment: If you want the string represenation of the whole array use `JSON.stringify(val)`, but I doubt you want to display something in this JSON format as it's not very user friendly.

Comment: @Mushroomator  - yeah tried that, not exactly what im looking for. thanks